# Golang connect to Twitter API returns unauthorized

Tags: rest, go, twitter

I tried to connect by using Postman, this works perfect. But when I write the code in Golang, for some reason it gives me a "Unauthorized" and I am unable to figure out why this might be.

My code below:

`url := "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets" method := "POST" payload := strings.NewReader(`{}`)

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"123\",oauth_token=\"123\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1680613888\",oauth_nonce=\"Bp1QKEfmyKU\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"123%3D\"")

res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer res.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(body))`
```

I tried to use packages and other stuff but I am unable to get those to work. I prefer to write HTTP requests myself either way, but I am unable to get it working.

I also copy and pasted the code that Postman generates but that code gives me the same error, eventhough it is working in the Postman app itself.

Hope someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong.

The error that is returned:

{
"title": "Unauthorized",
"type": "about:blank",
"status": 401,
"detail": "Unauthorized"
}

Comment: Can it be simply explained by [Twitter having had banned 3rd-party apps](https://www.engadget.com/twitter-new-developer-terms-ban-third-party-clients-211247096.html)? Like, it fingerprints your request (say, by the "User-Agent" header field and/or otherwise) and still allows Postman but rejects your program?

Comment: Where is the value for your `Authorization` header coming from? Is Postman generating this per request? I assume your `oauth_timestamp` etc. should be per request, so copying from Postman over to your code wouldn't work since that timestamp is too old..

Comment: Good one, I will try and automate that one, will update my post.